# Como abrir submenu só de passar por cima do menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte Menu em css:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"> 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
        <li class="scroll <? if(!$this->uri->segment(1)) echo "active"; ?>"><a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li> 
        <li class="scroll <? if($this->uri->segment(1)=='empresa') echo "active"; ?>"><a href="<? echo base_url("empresa/detalhes/1/sobre-a-nuclemig"); ?>">Institucional</a></li> 
        <li class="scroll <? if($this->uri->segment(1)=='curso') echo "active"; ?>"><a href="<? echo base_url("curso"); ?>">Cursos</a></li> 
        <li class="scroll <? if($this->uri->segment(1)=='unidade') echo "active"; ?>"><a href="<? echo base_url("unidade"); ?>">Unidades</a></li> 
        <li class="scroll"><a style="cursor:pointer" id="manual-ajax">Quero Desconto</a></li> 
        <li class="scroll <? if($this->uri->segment(1)=='vantagem') echo "active"; ?>"><a href="<? echo base_url("vantagem"); ?>">Vantagens Exclusivas</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="">Design</a><li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="">Development</a><li>
            <li class="scroll"><a href="">Marketing</a><li>
          </ul>                     
        </li> 
        <li class="scroll <? if($this->uri->segment(1)=='depoimento') echo "active"; ?>"><a href="<? echo base_url("depoimento"); ?>">Depoimentos</a></li> 
        <li class="scroll <? if($this->uri->segment(1)=='faleconosco') echo "active"; ?>"><a href="<? echo base_url("faleconosco"); ?>">Fale Conosco</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Preciso que ao passar o mouse em vantagem, por exemplo, desça o submenu, como posso fazer isso? Estou usando a classe normal do bootstrap para gerenciar o menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basta adicionares o CSS:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu
{ 
    display: block; 
}
```

ou seja, quando passas com o rato por cima (hover) do menu `li` o submenu `ul` é mostrado (`display: block;`)